# Horizontal line in ellipse

Tags: graphviz, use-case

I want to use graphviz for my use-cases, is there an easy way of getting a horizontal line in an ellipse shape?

image for reference:

[image: Use-case C]
<sub>(source: [highscore.de](http://www.highscore.de/uml/img/usecase_extend.gif))</sub>

if I use

`digraph G {
    Case [
        label = "{Use-Case C | Extension points \l blablabla}"
        shape = "record"
    ]
}`

I get a square with the horizontal line, but as soon as I change from record to ellipse the label has the text "{Use-Case C | Extension points \l blablabla}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, *ellipse* and *record* are different types of nodes. Vertical bar in record is used as a horizontal line just by convention. It is impossible to draw it in ellipse like that.

But there is a workaround here.

According to another [question about horizontal lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37737932/html-horizontal-line-error-graphviz) you can try HTML labels while using tables. They won't give you exactly what you want. Still, it is possible to draw label like that:

```
digraph structs {
  node [shape=ellipse]
  A [label=<
    <TABLE BORDER="0" CELLSPACING="0">
      <TR><TD>top</TD></TR>
      <HR/>
      <TR><TD>bottom</TD></TR>
    </TABLE>
  >];
  B [label="Hello, Graphviz"];
  A -> B;
}
```

Whereas the result looks like:

[image]

Ultimately, you may try [creating your custom shape](http://www.graphviz.org/wiki/how-create-custom-shapes)